# Resize container on screen orientation and trigger from resize

Tags: javascript

Really new to Javascript, I have a code that I have to use inside an app  that works fine for changing attributes reading width and height proportions.
I can now trigger this action and when the container show it will render the shape assigned, so it works ok.

In the app I  can insert the function "On Show" on "Initialization" etc but not on resize or on orientation, so is not reading live Events and when a rotation happens or browser window resize, it won't be listening to the change.  If I close and reopen the container will be fine.

So I need to incorporate the listening to event.
Any Help?

**this is my code:**

```
var container = this.getComponentByName('Container_Name');
 const { clientWidth, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

if (clientHeight > clientWidth) {
   container.set('width', 600);
   container.set('height', 300);
  } else {
   container.set('width', 220);
   container.set('height', 400);
  }
```

I need this function to run OnShow like already does and to run onOrientationChange()

Any help appreciated
onOrientationChange()

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you use the [orientation CSS media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) to do this, rather than Javascript. It will be easier to implement and operate more reliably.

When you run this snippet, make sure you use the **full page** link, then adjust your browser window into portrait and then landscape sizes to test the responsiveness.

```css
/* base styles specify what we want for portrait orientation */
.morph {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* override styles for any changes we want for landscape orientation */
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .morph {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="morph"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect changes in orientation or resizing with JS, add an event listener.

In your it would be a `resize` event.

So it'll look something like this:

```
var container = this.getComponentByName('Container_Name'); 
const { clientWidth, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

const resizeContainer = () => { 
  if (clientHeight > clientWidth) {
   container.set('width', 600);
   container.set('height', 300);
  } else {
   container.set('width', 220);
   container.set('height', 400);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', e => resizeContainer());
```

Here's more info on JS event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

However, if you're just updating the container size, you'll just need CSS to set the `width` and `height` and use JS to trigger CSS class toggle.